# Plotting with sub and superscripts on the PlotLabels

Tags: plotting, bugs, legending, labeling, subscript

**Bug persists through 12.0.**

---

I'm trying to produce a plot with `PlotLabels` that include sub- and superscripts. However, I haven't been able to do it consistently. Currently I'm trying to do this with the basic math assistant palette and the code is thus:

```
Plot[30, {x, 0, 605}, PlotStyle -> {Dashed, Thick, Black}, 
PlotLabels -> "\!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(x\), \(s\), \(*\)]\)"]
```

But there is rather strange gap between the plot and the label which you can see from the picture below. Is there a way to move the label closer to the plot?

[image]

Running the same code without the sub and superscripts produces no issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like a bug in `PlotLabels` to me - my guess is that when measuring the size of the label, it does not take into account how big the rendered string will be, only the raw (rather long) string. A work-around is to wrap the label in `Row@{...}`:

```
Plot[30, {x, 0, 605},
 PlotStyle -> {Dashed, Thick, Black}, 
 PlotLabels -> Row@{
  "\!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(x\), \(s\), \(*\)]\)"
 }
]
```

[image]

Other potential wrappers include `StandardForm[...]` and `TraditionalForm[...]` (which will render the label a bit differently) - essentially anything that hides the raw string from `PlotLabels` seems to do the trick.

Comment: Ah that explains why removing either the sub or the superscript only made the gap slightly shorter. I tried couple of workarounds with InputForm etc. without a positive results. However, Row seems to do it. Thank you.

Comment: @HartoSaarinen Please consider writing a bug report on the issue to support(at)wolfram.com.

Comment: `Pane` also works as well for a workaround